# With RethinkDB, how would one implement a tag cloud?

Tags: rethinkdb

Suppose I have the tables (with example data):

```
 story
 {id: 1, name: 'First Story', tags: ['plants', 'flowers']}
 {id: 1, name: 'Second Story', tags: ['flowers', 'wedding']}

 tag
 {id: 'plants'}
 {id: 'flowers'}
 {id: 'weddings'}
```

The story table has a multi index on the tags field.

Now how would I make a query that results in the amount of stories that each tag has (so it could be displayed as a tag cloud). Ex:

```
 {"plants": 1, "flowers": 2, "wedding": 1}
```

or it could be in the format:

```
 [{id: "plants", count: 1}, {id: "flowers", count: 2}, {id: "wedding", count: 1}]
```

And do it in a performant way, where a table with hundreds of thousands of stories and hundreds of tags will complete the query quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
r.table("story").indexCreate("tags", {multi: true}).run(...)
r.table("story").group({index: "tags"}).count().run(...)
```

If you want to prettify the result of the group/count, you can do

```
r.table("story").group({index: "tags"}).count().ungroup().map(function(result) {
  return r.object(result("group"), result("reduction"))
})
```

Comment: `r.table("story").group({index: "tags"}).count().run(...)` works nicely, but the one with the map results in a `Cannot convert NUMBER to SEQUENCE` error.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to call `ungroup`. I just edited the query, it should work fine now.

Comment: I found that with an additional reduce, the result is prettier (a single object instead of array of objects):  
`r.table("story").group({index: "tags"}).count().ungroup().map(function(result) {
  return r.object(result("group"), result("reduction"))
}).reduce( function(left, right) {return left.merge(right)} )`